# How to use my custom syscall from the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel, system-calls

My system call takes an integer and returns long. I can use it in a C code like `syscall(549,1)`. But I would like to use it from the terminal not from a C code. Can you please help me?

Comment: The shell doesn't provide a way to make arbitrary system calls.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Another, how can I use my syscall in a C code with its name instead of writing syscall(549,1) ?

Comment: Wrap it in a function that calls `syscall(549, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can directly use your system call from the shell. Although, you can write a simple C program, compile it and add its location to the **PATH** directly or put in in **/usr/local/bin**. Then you will be able to call this binary directly from the shell.

The code of your C program would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%ld\n", syscall(549, (int) strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0)));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @MarcAryan if you believe the answer is the best solution to your problem, you may accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Perl is installed on every linux I know about

```bash
syscall(){
  local sys=$1
  perl -e "require qw/syscall.ph/; syscall(SYS_$sys())"
}

syscall sched_yield
```